# How to get SRID from .prj file in PHP using OGR2OGR in PHP

Tags: ogr2ogr, php, srid, prj

I'm writing a PHP script that uses the OGR2OGR command to open a .prj file and get its SRID. I'm using the following code:

```
$prjPath=Storage::path(filename);
$output = shell_exec("ogrinfo -al -so $prjPath");
preg_match('/AUTHORITY\["EPSG","(\d+)"\]/', $output, $matches);
```

However, I'm getting the error "Unable to open datasource with the following drivers" when trying to open the .prj file. I'm sure the .prj file exists and the path is correct.

Is there a way to get the SRID of a .prj file using OGR2OGR? Or is there another way to get the SRID of a .prj file in PHP?

Comment: `ogrinfo` is expecting a datasource.  A .prj is one of the files that make up a shapefile, pass the .shp to `ogrinfo`.